# How to securely update model from form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In my app I want to prompt the user to answer a question. Before the user sees the question, I have it already stored in my database where the **user_answer** field is null. When a user wants to answer a question a form will pop up in the template and then the answer provided will be updated in the model.

The code below does this. However, I'm currently injecting the question_id as a hidden field within my form. I'm suspecting this isn't a best practice as this field could be tampered by an attacker who could change the id and potentially make me modify a different question in the model. How can I pass back the question_id field from the template form back to the model in a secure and reliable manner?

This is my model:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

My form:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    question_id = forms.IntegerField()
    user_answer = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My view:

```
def question(request, question_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            q = Question.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['question_id'])
            q.user_answer = form.cleaned_data['user_answer']
            q.save()

            return render(request, 'done.html', {'form':form.cleaned_data})
        else:
            return render(request, 'home.html')
    else:
        question = get_list_or_404(Question, id=question_id)

        form = QuestionForm({'question_id':question.id})

        return render(request, 'quiz.html', {'question':question, 'form':form})
```

And the form within the template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'question' question.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.question_id.as_hidden }}
    {{ question.question }}
    <br>
    {{ form.user_answer }}
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass the `question_id` as hidden? Can't you just get the question id from `{% url 'question' question.id %}` and use it to get the correct `Question` object?

Comment: instead of `id` you can use `uuid` or `slug` so that the attacker won't able to guess the next id